# как получить количество row в запросе?

Tags: php

ДД!

Имеется БД Oracle.
Есть таблица cars.
Как получить все строки этой таблицы, для того чтоб в дальнейшим сделать цикл, который будет получать по 100 строк с таблицы cars.
Количество мне известно 24073rows.
Теперь как мне использовать mysql_fetch_array в Оракл((((

```
$queryCount = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_row FROM cars
```

Спасибо!

Comment: Во-первых, забудьте про расширение `mysql` - используйте `PDO` или `mysqli` на худой конец. Во-вторых - перед тем как идти сюда вы уже ознакомились с документацией и синтаксисом SQL?

Comment: а зачем вам вообще знать число строк чтобы порциями перебрать всю таблицу? Берёте `select ... from cars where primary_key > ? order by primary_key limit 1000` и обходите всю таблицу подставляя в очередной запрос PK последней встреченной строки.

Comment: Я закрываю вопрос исходя из предположения, что автор имеет ввиду БД Oracle Mysql. Если же имеется в виду БД Oracle, то ответ будет практически таким же, только код соединения с БД в PDO будет другим